# IdentityRoles in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-authorization

I try to build a web app with ASP.NET Core. I build it with Identity and not JWT (not familiar with that technology).

My app is limited which means I know who will access it (around 10 people), therefore, I want to give each one of them a different role, and of course I will be the admin.

I have few users here as you can see, this is the `AspNetUsers` table:

[image: I have few users here as you can see, this is AspNetUsers table]

Here I have my `AspNetRoles` table:

[image]

And here is my `AspNetUserRoles` table:

[image]

I tried this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

None of these attempts seems to be working.. I still get access denied..

I added this to my `program.cs`:

[image]

I use ASP.NET Core 6 (I think).

I have 2 databases, one for my app, other came with the project for identity and authentication.

If someone can give an answer, please be let it be in detail with examples.

Answer (score -1):

If you want role-based authorization ，you could set as below ：

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<....>(options => options.......)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<.....>();
```

in your controller:add`[Authorize(Roles ="....")]`

**Update**:
I tried as below and it works well:

[image]
[image]

added `[Authorize(Roles ="SomeRole")]` on Privay Page:
[image]
then I modified to `[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]`

The Result:
[image]

Comment: Ruikai Feng, this is not working. both exists when I change AddRoles<IdentityUser> to IdentityRole the app is not running.

Comment: I‘ve updated my answer,in my case,it works well,could you upload your project to github

Comment: I still got access denied. Is there any chance for remote control instead of uploading it?